# Team Foundation - can I set it to only allow 1 user to edit?

Tags: tfs

I'm new to Team Foundation and was wondering if it's possible to disallow other people from editing (checking out) a document that I have checked out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in Visual Studio go to **Team**, **Team Project Settings**, **Source Control...**

The first option there is Enable multiple check-out.

You may also have to disable Local Workspaces if you have them enabled in your Version of TFS.

Generally this is not necessary any more. Most modern Centralised Version Control Systems allow this and can handle merging pretty well.